# XSLT: how to check numerous nodes for a certain value applied to all of them

Tags: xslt, xpath, grouping

I have the following simplified XML source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MVKE>
<item>
    <MANDT>025</MANDT>
    <MATNR>000000000000000551</MATNR>
    <VMSTA>2</VMSTA>
</item>
<item>
    <MANDT>025</MANDT>
    <MATNR>000000000000000551</MATNR>
    <VMSTA>2</VMSTA>
</item>
<item>
    <MANDT>025</MANDT>
    <MATNR>000000000000000551</MATNR>   
    <VMSTA>2</VMSTA>
</item>
</MVKE>
```

and I need to compare the `<VMSTA>` values. If they are all "2" then my flag-value in the target XML should say "true" otherwise "false".

I have come up with this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <list>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="MVKE"/>
    </list>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="MVKE">
    <flag>
        <xsl:for-each select="item">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when
                    test="(preceding-sibling::*[1]/VMSTA or self::*/VMSTA = current()/VMSTA) and (current()/VMSTA='2')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'true'"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="'false'"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </flag>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but the output is always

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list>
<flag>truetruetrue</flag>
</list>
```

because of the `<xsl:for-each>`. I have also tried it with keys on `<VMSTA>` but that also gave me 3 values in `<flag>`. How can I compare the 3 properly and only get one value in `<flag>`? Am I just thinking to complicated?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need a `for-each`. Assuming the context node is an `MVKE` element (as in your example), the following expression returns `true` when all `VMSTA` elements have a string value equal to `2` (and `false` when any other value is present):

```
not(item/VMSTA[not(.='2')])
```

This works because of the implicit conversion of `item/VMSTA[not(.='2')]` into a boolean. A node-set's boolean value is `true` if and only if it is non-empty. Therefore, `item/VMSTA[not(.='2')]` is `true` whenever it selects at least one node, which is when there exists a `VMSTA` element whose string value is not `2`. Wrapping the expression in `not()` produces its negation, which is the desired result.

Complete example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <list><xsl:apply-templates select="MVKE"/></list>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="MVKE">
        <flag><xsl:value-of select="not(item/VMSTA[not(.='2')])"/></flag>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Nice explanation and example.

Comment: hello lwburk, thank you for your good explanation and the example +1

Comment: Excellent, I have the same situation and I never would have thought the solution could be so simple :)

Answer (score 3):

**Just use**:

```
not(/*/*/VMSTA[not(. = '2')])
```

This XPath expression evaluates to `false()` if there exists an element `/*/*/VMSTA`, whose string value is different from the string `"2"`.

Otherwise `true()`.

**This may be referred to as the** "*law of double negation*`

Comment: thank you Dimitre for your explanation. I have to have a look at that XPATH too.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a key to get a group of nodes with different values for `<VMSTA/>`.  If the group only has one node, then all the values are identical:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:key name="dupes" match="VMSTA" use="."/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="vmsta-count"
                    select="count(//VMSTA[generate-id() =
                                   generate-id(key('dupes', .))])"/>
      <list>
        <flag>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$vmsta-count = 1">
              <xsl:text>true</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:text>false</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </flag>
      </list>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run against your provided source results in:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<list>
  <flag>true</flag>
</list>
```

But, this is a general-case solution, and doesn't care about the actual value, just differences in value.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is a nice alternative, albeit a bit hacky. But then again how can one not appreciate an elegant hack :)

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester: Compared to the other answers it's definitely not as direct; and in regards to the OP, it's definitely not as direct.  It's more general, which may or may not have been needed, but it was fun figuring out.