# Extra question on "XSL - Create Multiple Tables According to The Different Values Of An XML Child Node"

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Mr. **Zach Young**, in continuation of your excellent answer in question:
[XSLT: how to check numerous nodes for a certain value applied to all of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021444/xslt-how-to-check-numerous-nodes-for-a-certain-value-applied-to-all-of-them)
Please help us on how to add numbering in your code, starting on the first row of the first table and continue to each one of the next ones, excluding the same items. Numbering must augment from the last raw of each table
Thank you very much in advance.